# 1C 8.3 Движение товаров на складе/складах

Tags: 1с

1С Предприятие. ПОдскажите, Могу посмотреть только через оборотно-сальдовую ведомость и то не понятно правильно или нет. Но самого движения там нет.

Есть другие варианты?

P.S. я нуб в данной теме, поэтому не ругайтесь)

Comment: mista.ru вам в помощь, задайте вопрос там.

Comment: В вопросе следует указать в какой конфигурации Вы работаете ...

Answer (score 0):

Движения создаются документами.
Если вы не уверены, делает документ движения или нет, нажмите в документе кнопку:

- Перейти -> Движения документа по регистрам

Или кнопка:

- "Ещё" -> Отчеты -> Движения документов

PS В разных конфигурациях 1С может быть по разному. Если напишите свою версию, будет проще.